# How can I supress system() from printing to screen?

Tags: php

Trying to test how long mongo takes to retrieve each document.

However, `system()` prints the result to screen and I think that may slow down the process.

How could I supress it from printing to screen?

```
<?php
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB("test");
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, "fakestat");
for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++){
        $index[]=rand(1,432050);
}
$fp = fopen('logTime.txt','w');
fwrite($fp, "startTimeSec\t startTimeNanoSec\t endTimeSec\t endTimeNanoSec\n");

foreach($index as $val) {
        $startTime = system("date +%s'\t'%N");
        $results[] = $collection->findOne(array("capture"=>"$val"));
        $endTime = system("date +%s'\t'%N");
        fwrite($fp, sprintf("%s\t %s\n", $startTime, $endTime));
}
fclose($fp);
$m->close();
?>
```

Update: Using `exec()` and it seems to be work abeit still rather slow.

Comment: why would you use system to get the data? look at example one for how to time  a script properly: [microtime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

Comment: dont use system, use `DateTime`. Why use php if you're just going to use cmd/bash?

Comment: I wanted to see nano second granularity. I don't think those calls return nano seconds?

Comment: @resting, nanosecond granularity is irrelevant if you need to spawn a process to get it. Not to mention that PHP's not the fastest gun in the West either.

Comment: @zneak True. I'll give `microtime()` a shot too.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Use [shell_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead of `system`

   ```
   $startTime = shell_exec("date +%s'\t'%N");
   ```
2. Use [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) instead.

   > microtime — Return current Unix timestamp with microseconds

   ```
   $startTime = microtime();
   ```

Comment: Keep in mind that almost all sane production environments in PHP have `shell_exec` and `exec` and the like in the disabled functions list.